# Zoom keeps changing its output audio volume

Tags: sound, volume-control, zoom-meeting

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, using the Zoom 5.5.4 client (but I experienced the problem with previous versions as well). More often than not (but weirdly enough not always), whenever I start or join a meeting, Zoom keeps changing its output audio volume. Most of the time, it is turned down to around 5-10% and I need to open my volume control to adjust it back before I can hear people.

In the Zoom settings I only see an option to prevent the *input* volume from being automatically adjusted, but that is not what I want...

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  Ubuntu has used the *year* format for specialist *snap* only releases that are intended for server usage; so you're more likely using a *deb* based desktop system such as Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (ie. *deb* based systems, both server & desktop are *year.month* in format; *year* being reserved for the specialist *snap* only products).  20 != 20.04

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wasn't aware. I edited it to 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, unchecking the option "Automatically adjust microphone volume" *does* solve the problem, even though it's not the microphone volume that is the culprit.

[image]

At least for me, that is how I got rid of the problem.